# How can I set a custom CKEditor on only one field?

Tags: nodes, forms, wysiwyg

I'm using Drupal 8.

I have a field that can only allow for specific styles, so I created a custom CKEditor and set the field to use it.

Now when I go to the field on the content edit form, I see the custom editor as the default, as well as a select menu to specify which editor I want to use to enter content.

When editing this field, I do not want to show any other editor options and I only want the editor to be used for this field.

What is the best way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Allowed Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/allowed_formats) does this (and nothing else). And has a stable release for D8 :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the module you want to add is [Better Formats](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_formats). This will let you specify format options for a field, if you only want to show one (even if the role has access to multiple).

Edit, because it is not clear from the project page:

```
composer require drupal/better_formats:1.x-dev
```

Comment: The Better Formats module is only for Drupal 7 :/

Comment: I'm using it on multiple projects. `composer require drupal/better_formats:1.x-dev`.